# How to test if a number is in a certain range to a number in the list

Tags: r, list

Imagine having a number x = 10 and a list of numbers list = (1, 8, 5).
Now I want my code to return "True" if the number is in a 2 point range to this list.

Which in this example should return true as the number 10 is in a 2 number range to 8, which is in the list.

More examples in case I was not precise enough:

```
x = 10, list = (1,7,5) -> False
x = 8, list = (1,8,5) -> True
```

Comment: You can use %in% `x %in% list`

Comment: But this will only give me True if X is part of the list. But I am also interested in cases where X+1 is in list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we can use

```
in.range = function(x, l, Range) {
  any(abs(l-x) <= Range)
}

in.range(10, c(1,8,3), 2)
# [1] TRUE
in.range(10, c(1,7,3), 2)
# [1] FALSE
```

Comment: Just beat me to it. Exactly the same function (with different objects' names).

Answer (score 0):

Set same sample data

```
mylist <- list(1, 8, 5)
```

This is how you test it  (and - for the record - you said it's a *list* of values, so I take your word on that):

```
x <- 10 
x <= max(unlist(mylist))+2 & x >= min(unlist(mylist))-2
# TRUE
x <- 11
x <= max(unlist(mylist))+2 & x >= min(unlist(mylist))-2
# FALSE
```